# Как вывести элементы списка через запятую без квадратных скобок?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in a:
    while a.count(i) > 1:
        a.remove(i)
print(a)
```

Нужно, чтобы вывод был такого вида:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код нормально и покажите примеры входных и реальных/желаемых выходных данных

Comment: вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем

Comment: for i in a:print(i) не подходит ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[print(i, end=", ") for i in a]
```

Числа выводятся как побочный эффект генерирования списка.

Comment: Только в конце будет лишняя запятая )

Answer (score 9):

Вот так вот:

```
print(*a, sep=', ')
```

https://ideone.com/clraT4

Answer (score 7):

Ну если очень хочется, то можно вывести список как строку через запятые, правда придётся перевести числа обратно в строковый вид:

```
print(', '.join(map(str,a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Квадратные скобки как раз и указывают на то, что это список.