# как выводить массив без скобок?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, файлы

Я создаю программу, но столкнулся с проблемой, что при открытитии текстового файла и выводе в отдельное окно я вижу странные скобки и текст находится по середине, а не по левой стороне экрана, что можно сделать в таком случае?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
file_idk = 'idk/idk.ccq'
text_file_idk = open(file_idk, 'a', encoding="utf-8")
text_file_idk1 = open(file_idk, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
kak1 = text_file_idk1.readlines()


def FAQ():
    win_FAQ = Toplevel(root)
    win_FAQ.title('FAQ')
    lbl_FAQ = Label(win_FAQ, text=kak1)
    lbl_FAQ.grid(row=0, column=0)


class Windows:
    def __init__(self):
        self.button_FAQ = Button(root, text='FAQ', foreground='black', background='white')

    def first_window(self):
        self.button_FAQ['command'] = FAQ
        self.button_FAQ.grid(column=3, row=0)


win = Windows()

win.first_window()

root.mainloop()
```

Вот так выглядит вывод:
[image]

Вывод должен быть таким:
[image]

То есть без скобок и равнение по левому краю окна.
idk.ccq это расширение у файла выдуманное.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1373483/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba?rq=1 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1163659/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba?rq=1

Comment: Я исправил мой вопрос, теперь аидно о чё я виду речь, то что вы мне прислали я пробывал и не работает

Comment: У меня к вам вопрос. Как я могу воспроизвести вашу проблему  на своем пк? Чтоб понять, что не так в вашем коде

Comment: Приведите воспроизводимый пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Сейчас исправлю, извеняюсь, я забыл это сделать(, торопился из дома уходить

Comment: Исправил, в коде расширение можете поменять на .txt

Comment: `readlines()` считывает файл в массив строк. читайте его лучше через `read()`